# ScrollView going to a specific content using a button

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiscrollview

Good afternoon

I have a viewcontroller containing some items on the menu and when I click on one of them I need it to go directly to the specific content of UIScrollView that in another viewcontroller
Each menu button leads to a different content ScrollView.

How could it?

Comment: What is this "another viewcontroller"? Can elaborate your question a little by providing some images or something that might help in your understanding the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem

If anyone needs help with this sent me a message

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by setting the scrollview.contentOffset property which is a CGPoint that uses X and Y to define the scroll position.

Comment: I solved the problem buddy, but thanks for your reply